# What application is good for note taking using tablets (printable in A4)?

Tags: software-recommendation

I have a tablet and I currently use Foxit PDF Reader and annotate PDFs with the pencil tool. Not very good as I cannot overwrite what I have just done. Eg. when I draw something, and want to add a few strokes to it, I cant as I will select the annotation instead.

GIMP/Photoshop will fix that, but I can't have multiple pages in a same file can I?

What application will be good for this? It need not work with PDF. Just something that will allow me to scrible notes/draw diagrams quickly, also printable in A4 pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Xournal

http://xournal.sourceforge.net/

sudo apt-get install xournal

and Gournal

http://www.adebenham.com/old-stuff/gournal/

Debian package available from developer page.

Good luck!